# How bitwise shift operator is Implemented in C. Is it atomic?

Tags: c

I want to know how bitwise shift operator `"<<"` and `">>"` is implemented in language. Is it atomic or not? Does c shift the whole word at once or move every bit one by one.

Are there any dependencies on the compiler, operating system or computer architecture?

Does C standard defines how shift operator would be implemented?

Example :

let's say two thread are accessing a data. one of them modifies it by shifting 3 bits. so does this 3 bit shift an atomic operation or not? should I use locks to handle this modification?

EDIT: It's only a shift operator, no store instruction. data is already in memory so no load operation. 
My processor : Powerpc MPC8569, e600 core architecture.

Comment: If the processor does not have a multi-bit shift instruction, then it cannot.

Comment: How would you be able to tell?

Comment: Compile a file for your desired arch, disassemble and look up the instruction it got compiled into. And there's your answer, for that arch/compiler combo.

Comment: "data is already in memory so no load operation" - Memory typically does not perform operations on data. I have doubts you really understood the very basics of how CPUs and memory work together. What did you find in the standard? Does it state they are atomic?

Comment: If your architecture has a shift instruction with a memory operand, then it is probably not atomic. Only read-modify-write operations that themselves implement synchronization primitives are normally made atomic. You may want to consult your platform documentation in any case.

Comment: @Olaf it makes no sense to talk about atomicity of register-only operations, as registers are not visible to other threads.

Comment: @n.m.: Which is another problem with those shifts. Yes, the first sentence of my comment is badly worded. The question is just too broad, it touches too many aspects.

Answer (score 5):

C only guarantees atomic access for `_Atomic` type variables, which were introduced in C11.

For all other situations, there are never any guarantees of atomic access. You will have to disassemble to C code to see how many assembler instructions it generated. Typically, one assembler instruction is always atomic.

But your question doesn't make all that much sense, because there is no context. Where would the result of the shift go? Do you plan to store it somewhere? Then that's two operations: shift and store. Possibly also a load. If you write an algorithm which is not atomic in itself, how do you expect the compiler to magically make it atomic for you?

Comment: sorry for being so abstract, My question is only about shift operator.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal atomic operations involve reads and writes. Shifting only produces a result without writing it anywhere so how is 
atomic relevant here?

Comment: let's say two thread are accessing a data. one of them modifies it by shifting 3 bits. so does this 3 bit shift a atomic operation or not ? should i use locks to handle this modification.

Comment: I guess , here is only shift operation, no write operation. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal: Operations and instructions are not the same. Very few architectures support full memory-memory ALU instructions. And even less often a compiler will use such operations. Even iff it works for some piece of code/compiler/optimisation settings, any modification can generate completely different code.

Comment: @Olaf : I have posted assembly code generated by compiler for different architecture. See the answer below. For one architecture it gives one instruction and for other it gives three instruction. So can i say if there is only one instruction, it should be atomic and if there are three instruction it can not be atomic.

Comment: "Typically, one assembler instruction is always atomic." Nope.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the processor that you are using.

If an instruction for bitwise shift is present, as is present on most x86 cores and 16 bit and 32 bit microcontrollers, then it is atomic.

If, however you have a 8 bit microcontroller without a bit shift instruction, or you are trying to bit shift a large value (say 64 bits or 128 bits) the instruction may well take quite a lot of code.

Comment: All CPUs have bitshift instructions. Not neccessarily the full set, but still. The presence of an instruction does not imply it is atomic.

Comment: No, native x86 shifts with memory operands are not atomic, and I guess this is true about most modern CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon which standard you are talking about.

AFAIU, the only atomic operations (explicitly defined as atomic) in C11 are the ones related to [`<stdatomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)

You could imagine a TeraHertz processor with a 4 bits ALU; even a simple `int32_t` addition won't be atomic on it.

Comment: As the older versions don't even cover this subject, it can only relate to C11 in terms of the standard's semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two program

```
 #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
   int i = 5;
   return 0;
   }
```

Its assembly code generated for PowerPC architecture Code 1 is

```
    .file   "hello.c"
    .section    ".text"
    .align 2
    .globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    stwu 1,-32(1)
    stw 31,28(1)
    mr 31,1
    li 0,5
    stw 0,8(31)
    li 0,0
    mr 3,0
    lwz 11,0(1)
    lwz 31,-4(11)
    mr 1,11
    blr
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.2.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Second code is

```
 #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
   int i = 5;
   i = i<<1;
   return 0;
   }
```

My assembly code generated for PowerPC architecture code 2 is

```
        .file   "hello.c"
        .section    ".text"
        .align 2
        .globl main
        .type   main, @function
    main:
        stwu 1,-32(1)
        stw 31,28(1)
        mr 31,1
        li 0,5
        stw 0,8(31)
        lwz 0,8(31) // extra 
        slwi 0,0,1  // extra
        stw 0,8(31) // extra 
        li 0,0
        mr 3,0
        lwz 11,0(1)
        lwz 31,-4(11)
        mr 1,11
        blr
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.2.2"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

You see there are three extra Instruction, So operation is not atomic

I also compiled this on Intel i7 PC. Here are the results:

assembly code generated for first code is :

```
    .file   "hello.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Assembly code generated for code 2:

```
    .file   "hello.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    sall    -4(%rbp) // only one extra instruction 
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

So, my understanding is that, answer depends on architecture we are using.

Comment: You just state the obvious. But it depends on more than just the CPU instruction set and addressing modes. Relying on the compiler generating specific code is invitation to disaster.

Comment: PowerPC, like any RISC architecture, uses a load-store design. It doesn't have instructions that can operate directly on memory. It has to load the value from memory, operate on it, and then store it back. x86, however, *can* operate directly on values in memory—at least there is a single instruction to do so. But that doesn't mean that the operation is atomic. The types of instructions involving memory operands are separated into multiple micro-ops in the processor. A single instruction does not imply that something is atomic, nor do multiple instructions imply that it is not.

Comment: @CodyGray: In addition, the compiler might choose to load the result or source to register for optimisations, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Normally it should be SHLD/SHRD - Double Precision Shift (386+)
https://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/shld_shrd.html

I think it's atomic because it's a single instruction. Otherwise you could use atomic or volatile if c supports it, C++11 supports it.

Comment: Single instructions does not mean they are atomic. Even if they are for the single code, they are not in the C sense.